# Solution of differential equation $4xy’’+2y’+y=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

If $y(x)$ is a solution of the equation $$4xy’’+2y’+y=0, y(0)=1$$ Then $y’’(0)$ is equal to

$1$. $1/24$.

$2$. $1/12$.

$3$. $1/6$.

$4$.  $1/2$.

Actually it was  $3$ minutes question in exam so I have to take less time . I was unable to solve it . Firstly I think it can be reduced to Cauchy Euler equation which was not possible by multiple of $x$. Secondly I think reduction of order is possible then one solution is neither given nor easy to find . Power series solution method is not in my syllabus. How to solve it in less time . Please help.  Thank you  .

Comment: Differentiate the DE  and note that $y'(0)=-1/2$  $\implies 6y''(0)=-y'(0)$ $\implies y''(0)=1/12$

Comment: @user577215664 after differentiate where is $y’’’$?

Comment: The factor of $y'''$ is $x$ and $x=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiate the DE  and note that $y'(0)=-1/2$
$$4xy’’+2y’+y=0$$
$$4xy’'’+6y''+y'=0$$

$\implies 6y''(0)=-y'(0)$ $\implies y''(0)=1/12$

Comment: thank you . Now I got . I was thinking of methods only .

Comment: You're welcome  @neelkanth